# How to update data in a production database in Laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have two tables `users` and `user_informations`. They were linked by a one-to-one relationship.

Now I want to merge them and delete the `user_informations` table without loosing the data in the database or resetting the whole migrations.

What is the best way to do it?

My current structure of the tables are

`users(id, name, password, remember_token, timestamps)`

`user_informations(id, user_id, first_name, last_name, avatar, description, timestamps)`

I want to merge `first_name` and `last_name` to one string and add it to the `name` field of users and move `avatar` and `description` to the users table.

Comment: please provide your table structure, also show what you have tried so far..

Comment: Add `user_infomations` table data to `users` table, than drop `user_infomations` table.

Comment: I meant how to do it correctly. I made a migration that will add two columns to the `users` table and made a seeder that will merge the data, after that, another migration will delete the `user_informations` table. But when I move it to the server and run the `migrate` command it will delete the `user_informations` table before running the seeder.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small script which takes data from `user_informations` and adds it to the `users` table. Something like:

```
User::chunk(1000, function ($users) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $user->update($user->user_informations);
    }
});
```

Comment: Where should I write this? How should I handle the migrations? I wrote a similar script in a seeder, but when I will move the migrations and seeder to the server, it will delete the `user_informations` table before I could run the seeder. As there are two migrations needed for this change one for adding the columns to `users` table another to delete `user_informations` table.

Comment: It depends on the situation. If you have data and want to transfer it to the `users` table just once, just put the code into a simple closure inside routes file and run it. Then fix the migrations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make three steps :

- you need to make a migration for the user table, to make it contains user information
- make a command that loop for the users and get the values from `user_infomations` table
- make a migration to delete`user_infomations`table after checking that everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a dedicated seeder class which I then call in a particular migration file. This way I don't have to create a separate artisan command.

```php
<?php

// ... regular migration file

public function up()
{
    // Run your regular Schema::...() methods here to create / update tables, if needed.
 
    // Call dedicated seeder
    Artisan::call('db:seed', [
        '--class' => 'DbRefactor/SeederClassForThisMigrationSample',
        '--force' => true // Make sure it also runs in production environment
    ]);
}

// In the down() method you could also call a seeder which would do a 'reverse', if needed.
```